# Union query to hide records that have a blank in a specific field

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, union

I've got a query that returns values from two tables:

- SpecSheet which is static and has all product codes
- InputWalls which is tied to a userform that allows people to select the code.

A Join argument is used, Join takes the 'InputSheet.*codes*' & 'SpecSheet.Code' as the target to match on both tables. Problem I have is that if Inputsheet.code is empty, It will still try pull the record of everything with it.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
    "Kitchen Main Walls" AS Type, InputWalls.Client, InputWalls.Site, InputWalls.PlotNO, InputWalls.KitchenMainCode, SpecSheet.DESCRIPTIONONE, SpecSheet.DESCRIPTIONTWO, SpecSheet.SIZE, SpecSheet.BOXQTY
FROM 
    InputWalls LEFT JOIN SpecSheet ON (InputWalls.Client = SpecSheet.Client) AND (InputWalls.KitchenMainCode = SpecSheet.Code)
WHERE 
    (((InputWalls.Client)="BARRATT") And ((InputWalls.Site)="LG") And ((InputWalls.PlotNO)="1"));
        
UNION ALL 

SELECT 
     "Kitchen Feature Walls" AS Type, InputWalls.Client, InputWalls.Site, InputWalls.PlotNO, InputWalls.KitchenFeatureCode, SpecSheet.DESCRIPTIONONE, SpecSheet.DESCRIPTIONTWO, SpecSheet.SIZE, SpecSheet.BOXQTY
FROM 
     InputWalls LEFT JOIN SpecSheet ON (InputWalls.Client = SpecSheet.Client) AND (InputWalls.KitchenFeatureCode = SpecSheet.Code)
WHERE 
     (((InputWalls.Client)=Forms!MainMenu!ClientSearch.value) And ((InputWalls.Site)=Forms!MainMenu!SiteSearch.value) And ((InputWalls.PlotNO)=Forms!MainMenu!PlotSearch.value));
```

I have tried looking online for a solution, but I got nothing when It come to targeting a specific field. Kind regards.

Comment: You have nothing in your code about `InputSheet`, so I'm guessing you mean `InputWalls`?   Nowhere in your query are you excluding anything from InputWalls.  You have it as the driver table in a left join (`InputWalls LEFT JOIN SpecSheet`), so your query will return every row from that table, whether it has a match in the optional table or not.

Comment: Input Walls, My apologies, how do I skip if the code.value = null/empty?

Comment: Include it in your where clause.  In standard SQL I would use `and trim(coalesce(InputWalls.code,'')) <> ''`. That would handle nulls, empty string, or any amount of white space.  Sorry, not sure how to write that in Access SQL.

Comment: That's indeed correct, however instead of the wild card I've used predefined fields. My issue is that because I have used a join command, I think im over thinking it *That and my SQL skills are lacking

Comment: Its a string, The Code is made up of the 1st 3 characters of the client name and some numbers, I will try the above now,

Comment: That works, It does literally bring everything up from just Input walls though, minus the blank code values

Comment: You Sir are a genius, I worked out what you we're asking me to do and Len(KitchenMainCode & "") > 0 is perfect. 

Thanks for being so patient